# How do I randomly jumble sections of a URL seperated by "/"?

Tags: php, url, random, shuffle

I’m wondering how to jumble sections of this URL as `/` as the separator:

```
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t1/
```

I’m looking for all combinations of results, like

```
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t1/
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/x
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products
http://fujifilm.in/en/products
http://fujifilm.in/en/
http://fujifilm.in/
http://fujifilm.in/en/fujifilm_x_t1/
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/fujifilm_x_t1/
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/fujifilm_x_t1/
http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/fujifilm_x_t1/
................
................
................
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining why you would want this. If it is to obtain some sort of SEO effect, I would advice against it. You might be having a so-called [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Good Question Nanne ! I need to get a shorter version of url, For example have a look of  [http://flipkart.com/item/MOBDTH3DMB7GEZEK](http://flipkart.com/item/MOBDTH3DMB7GEZEK) on if you open this url it'll redirect to [http://www.flipkart.com/moto-x-16-gb/p/itmdthjkza6eburu?pid=MOBDTH3DMB7GEZEK](http://www.flipkart.com/moto-x-16-gb/p/itmdthjkza6eburu?pid=MOBDTH3DMB7GEZEK) for webpage scrapping i need this short url. Hope i made you clear.

Comment: @Vind What you ask for in your comment is completely different from what you ask for in your question. You might consider deleting your question and asking a new one? Your question should be **How to provide short redirect URL's for my content**

Comment: @Andresch Serj I don't feel like that, As like i mentioned in above comment i need to find a short url, now i'm doing this manually. If i automate this, i can use this [tool](http://www.dytek3.com/seo-sem-tools/bulk-website-url-status-check/) to find whether it's available or not. Any more questions on my method ?

Comment: @Vind: What you describe in your question is a quite unique request to get all possible jumbled version of a long url. What you search for as mentioned in the comments is a hopefully unique, short url. The later can be done with a one liner `substr(md5(url),0,8)` and checking for colision for *just in case*. Nontheless, i actually wnt thru the hassle to answer your initial question. And it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$uri = 'http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t1/';

$parts = parse_url($uri);
$path = $parts['path'];
$sections = explode('/', $path);
foreach ($sections as $k => $v) {
    if (!$v) {
        unset($sections[$k]);
    }
}
shuffle($sections);
echo $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . '/' . implode('/', $sections) . '/' . PHP_EOL;
```

The above outputs only one random permutation of the URL path. Tweaking the `shuffle()` function to give all possible outputs, and then putting the `echo` in a `foreach` loop should be reasonably straightforward. To get you started here’s a question about [getting all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797578). Changing that to work with arrays shouldn’t be too difficult.

Comment: Not exactly what i required, but i got a clue from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if it actually is what you want (due to your comment) but to answer the question for future visitors:

```
<?php

function jumbleUrl($url) {
  // $jumbledUrls will be our result array  
  $jumbledUrls = array();
    
  // first strip and backup the domain and protocol
  $protocol = substr($url,0,stripos($url,'//')+2);
  $urlRemaining = substr($url,strlen($protocol));

  $domain = substr($urlRemaining,0,stripos($urlRemaining,'/')+1);
  $urlRemaining = trim(substr($urlRemaining,strlen($domain)),'/');

  // create array of remaining url parts
  $jumbleParts = explode('/',$urlRemaining);

  /**
   * now we use our jumbleable parts as numbers in our own number system and 
   * count thru all possibilities. See Text below.
   */
  $jumblePartsCount = count($jumbleParts);
  $possibilities = pow($jumblePartsCount,$jumblePartsCount);

  for ($i = 0; $i <= $possibilities; $i++) {
    // now we have to find the combination representing our number.
    // basically we have to convet our base 10 number to our base $possibilities number
    // Luckily php has a function for that:
    $possibilityNr = base_convert ( $i , 10 , count($jumbleParts) );
    
    // Now we take each "digit" of our possibilites Nr and take the 
    // jumbleablePart it represents
    $jumbledUrl = '';
   
    /** 
     * assuming you do not want jumbled urls like example.org/peter/peter/frank we
     * prevent parts from occuring more than once in an url.
     */
    $doublesPreventer = array();
    $doublesOccured   = false;
    for ($j=0;$j < strlen($possibilityNr);$j++) {
        $digit = intval(substr($possibilityNr,$j,1));
        if(in_array($digit,$doublesPreventer)) {
          $doublesOccured = true;
          break;
        }
        else {
          $jumbledUrl .= $jumbleParts[$digit].'/';
          $doublesPreventer[] = $digit;
        }
    }

    if(!$doublesOccured) {
    // Now we have a jumbled url and store it to our array of jumbled urls
        $jumbledUrls[] = $protocol . $domain . $jumbledUrl;
        
    }
  }

  return $jumbledUrls;
}

$url = 'http://fujifilm.in/en/products/consumer_products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t1/';
$jumbledUrls = jumbleUrl($url);

var_dump($jumbledUrls);
```

See code running [here](http://ideone.com/QHGlPy) (*might not work due to ideone memory restrictions*).

If you see your jumbleable parts as numbers you can easily calculate how many possibilietes there are. If you have 10 parts, your numeric system stays the same and you have a 10 digit long number representing your possibilities: 9,999.999.999 + 1 possibilities right?

If you have less, let's say like in your example 6 parts, you have 6^6 possibilities (46656).

Read up on ...

- [Radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)
- [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics)
- [base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)
- [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
- [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)
- and [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

... to understand how it works.

**WARNING**: It only works if you do not have more than 36 slashes (jumbleable parts) due to restrictions in the PHP base_convert method.

Comment: Sorry this is not what i asked for.

Comment: Wrong. It is exactly what you asked for: *I’m looking for all combinations of results, like ...*. Might not be what you wanted, but still is what you asked for. I tried to clear that in the comments but you disagreed and stated it IS what you want: All possible combinations of jumbled up url given. Took some time to write it as well - and was fun to write as well. So ... whatever ;-p

Comment: This looks to be a better answer than mine, but it does give some invalid output, such as repeating the same section six times. I think the number of possibilities is n!, not n^n, if I'm reading the question correctly.

Comment: the possibility of combinations you have with n digits with base n is n^n is it not? Works out in testing. I am surely not a math genius thou  :-7  What part gets grepeated 6 times accidently? Fixed some bugs in my last edit BTW

Comment: Well, the last output is `fujifilm_x_t1/fujifilm_x_t1/fujifilm_x_t1/fujifilm_x_t1/fujifilm_x_t1/fujifilm_x_t1/`.

Comment: Oh, you're right .. thou he did not mention that those jumbles are out of the question right? Well, anyway ... i'll fix that.

Comment: @TRiG done. I now prevent doubles. Hopefully all this effort does not fall in the hand of SEO spammers ;-)