# stylize pagination controls with css

Tags: php, html, css, pagination

php

```
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a>';
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';      
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
```

html

```
<p class="pagination-controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></p>
```

ouput

Previous 1 [2] 3 Next

let's say `$pagenum = 2;`

I've added just the basic lines from php code and html, as I'm just simply echoing clickable buttons except the `$pagenum`, which is not a link. I'm not sure how can I target that with css so I can stylize that element. For other elements I can target by css selector -> `.pagination-controls a`. Would like to ask for your help how to target the $pagenum.

Comment: Wrap it in a `<span>` and style the span with a specific class.

Comment: This is basic BASIC coding. Add a span around it, and css it.

Comment: when I try to add a '<span>' the $pagenum variable goes hidden.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Not to be rude, but this is insanly simple to to. Add the open tag between the first two single quotes, and the close in front of the `&nbsp;`. You should not expect any real answers, this is something you should be able to do yourself

Comment: @vephelp if a `span` hides your `$pagenum` you probably either used the span wrong (*sry*) or you have some `span { display:none }` somewhere in your CSS.

Comment: @vephelp Your question is answered, your problem appears toi be something else and we gavbe you hints on how to find the source of the problem. Please consider accepting the answer since even thou it might not solve your problem, it did answer your question.

Comment: thanks! the problem was a typo. apologies as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a>';
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';      
$paginationCtrls .= '<span class="pagenum">'.$pagenum.' &nbsp;</span>';
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
```

access using selector `.pagination-controls span.pagenum`

If this does not help you, consider reading up on how HTML/CSS works.

Comment: tried doing this, but then the $pagenum is not displayed.

Comment: @vephelp as mentioned above: If this does not solve your problem, your problem is something different :-/ Maybe read up on how to work with HTML and CSS using Google? Find out about webdeveloper tools for firefox/chrome. That tool can help you find out why your pagination information is not there/not displayed.

Comment: IMO these kinds of topics should not get an answer. Adding a span is too simple to not think of, some dependant thinking should be promoted, the easy answer shouldn't :)

Comment: @Martijn i remember being a newbie so i answer almost everything. It may seem frustrating at times but it can also be fun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555654/how-do-i-randomly-jumble-sections-of-a-url-seperated-by/22558146#22558146 :D

Comment: I agree, some things appear to be plain magic, but adding a span and some css?

Comment: @Martijn Okay, next time i consider to just flag it. At least this person picked a name :D